# How can I make an html element disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website have a menu bar, when I making hover on an element the list will appear,

for example when user hover on "header" the section  "cbp-hrsub" will show,

I want If the user making hover out from the "cbp-hrsub" section the section will close in this moment.

this is the HTML Code

```
<div class="main">
        <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >header</a>
                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                            <div id="menu-list">
                                 <h4>Section One</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="menu-list">
                                    <h4>Section 2</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="menu-photo">
                                 <h4>The Image</h4>
                                 <ul>
                                        <li>
                                        <img src="themes/images/img.png" alt=""> 
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

and this is the javascrypt "jQuery" Code

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

    var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ),
        $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
        $body = $( 'body' ),
        current = -1;

    function init() {
        $menuItems.on( 'hover', open );
        $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
    }

    function open( event ) {

        if( current !== -1 ) {
            $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        }

        var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
            idx = $item.index();

        if( current === idx && event == 'click') {
            $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = -1;
        }
        else {
            $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
            current = idx;
            $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
        }

        return false;
    }



    function close( event ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = -1;
    }

    return { init : init };

})();
```

I wnat to add function If the user hover out from the section "cbp-hrsub"
it will close

any one can help me on this issue.

Comment: can you please share the minimum amount of css, because i can't reproduce the problem on js fidlle or stack overflow snippet editor

Comment: @ahmed, if there's something about this question that hasn't been covered in the duplicate (or many like it), please revise to make that more clear and we can consider re-opening the question.

Answer (score 0):

put the element you want to hover on and the element that is supposed to show in a tag (`#new_tag`). then use the following method:

```
$('#new_tag').on('mouseenter', function() {

      // your function to show content           

}).on('mouseleave', function(){

     // your function to show content 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make what you need by using CSS, no need for scripting

first you need to hide the sub menu that will be opened on hover

```
.cbp-hrsub {
  display: none;
}
```

and when you hover on the header change its display to block

```
#header:hover + .cbp-hrsub {
  display: block;
}
```

that's all
check working code in plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/zPzFYoBtjJS1GNYHEU49?p=preview